# How to trigger a flow from external call

Tags: angular, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, node-red

i'm new on node-red and trying to integrate this with a Hyperledger Client (that is baiscally Angular 4) and i need to **send an email** when the user **send a transaction** on hyperledger.

In the docs of Hyperledger (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/integrating/call-out - on example bellow), they say that is possible to "call Node-RED running on Bluemix", well, i run my own instance of local node-red, build a flow that start with a injection but i can't figure out:

**How to trigger that like they do in docs?**

I can't figure out too if is possible and how trigger this flow from Angular client (with something like a GET/POST request from client to node-red.)

Here my flow:
[NODE-RED FLOW EMAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF3OQ.png) 
(The flow actually works if clicked)

Thank you all! and sorry if is a bad question.

Answer (score 1):

Creating HTTP endpoints is covered in the Node-RED cookbook [here](https://cookbook.nodered.org/http/).

Basically:

- You drag a HTTP-in and a HTTP-response node on to the canvas
- Configure the HTTP-in node with the path you want it to listen on and the tpye of request it should accept (POST/GET...)
- Make sure that you let the input message flow though any other nodes you may add to complete the action you want to trigger
- include the HTTP-response node so the calling client actually gets a response rather than a timeout.

Comment: Thank you friend. Trough your link i able to learn how to do part of it.
But now i'm putting one call on angular app and make a test() button. Noting happens. When i go to the link (localhost:1880/hello) i get the email. Whats wrong??
test(){
       this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:1880/hello');

    }

Comment: Edit your original question or ask a new question if needed.